# Adding a pull to refresh feature to UIWebView iOS

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, uiwebview, refresh

I'm looking to add a Pull to refresh feature to a UIWebView that I have in an app. I've used Pull to refresh in the past on table views, but I'm struggling to find any good tutorials/libraries to help me add it to UIWebViews specifically and this project.

I did get some of the way using PullToRefreshView by chpwn (https://github.com/chpwn/PullToRefreshView) but I can't get it detecting the drag.
Does anyone know a better plug in/library?

Answer (score 3):

For me this post and code worked like a charm

http://sonnyparlin.com/2011/12/pulltorefresh-ios-5-and-arc-tutorial/

Comment: Really Really nice and easy to follow. I loved that post.

Comment: Downvoting because you should post the answer here, not merely a link to an outside reference. What happens when the link is dead? The link is broken now as a matter of fact!

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to iOS development, so this may not be the best way… but it worked for me.

I took the controller that was wrapping my WebView and I changed it to a UITableViewController (it was just a UIViewController previously) so that I could take advantage of the refreshControl property of that controller (ios6 and up). I'm not making use of the TableView inside of the UITableViewController (though, it does seem to require one to exist, which I include, but I just don't populate it). I added 2 methods to the controller:

```
- (void)addPullToRefresh
{
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull to Refresh"];

    [refreshControl addTarget:self.myWebView action:@selector(reload)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
}

- (void)stopRefresh 
{
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

I put a call to [self addPullToRefresh]; in viewDidLoad, and I added a call to [self stopRefresh]; in webViewDidFinishLoad:

I got my instructions for how to use the refreshControl property of UITableViewController [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/better-code-implement-pull-to-refresh-in-your-ios-apps/).